# .htaccess redirect but not always

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some problems making a working .htaccess-file. I have images and .css-files stored in a /inc/ folder, for example http://example.com/inc/style.css

Now, I want all URLs that do not start with http://example.com/inc/ "redirected" to http://example.com/, so if you call http://example.com/hello/fire/, that URL should be still in your address bar, but it loads http://example.com/. So the URL must not change in your address bar.

Does someone know how this works?

Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# This prevents the rewrite engine from looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If URI starts with "/inc/" do nothing (passthrough)
RewriteRule ^/?inc/ - [L]

# Otherwise if URI is at least 1 character (not "/"), rewrite to "/"
RewriteRule . / [L]
```